# problem undefined variable in sample program

Tags: octave

I am new to Octave and have found an interesting article (http://article.journalofchemicaleducation.com/pdf/wjce-3-6-1.pdf). I copied the code to start playing with it but I can not fond the problem: error: 'x' undefined near line 29 column 12
error: called from
diproticbuffer at line 29 column 4
solvediproticbuffer at line 2 column 1
solvediproticbuffer.

Could you please help me.

```
function [y] = diproticbuffer(x)
global c0;
global pK;
c0 = 10.^(-x);
y(1) = 1.0-(x(4)+x(1)-x(3))/pK(1);
y(2) = 1.0-(x(5)+x(1)-x(4))/pK(2);
y(3) = 1.0-(x(1)+x(2))/pK(3);
y(4) = 1.0-(c(5)+c(4)+c(3))/c0(1);
y(5) = 1.0-(c(2)+c(4)+2*c(5))/(c(1)+c0(2));
end

clear
source('diproticbuffer.m');
global c0;
c0 = [0.02; 0.015 ];
global pK;
pK = [3.46; 5.10; 14.0];
x0=[ 7; 7; 1.7; 8; 8 ];
[x, fval, info] = fsolve ('diproticbuffer', x0, optimset('TolFun',1.0E-8));
fprintf('Equilibrium concentrations\n');
fprintf('p[H+] = %8.4f->[H+] = %10.4E\n', x(1), 10^(-x(1)));
fprintf('p[OH-]= %8.4f->[OH-]= %10.4E\n', x(2), 10^(-x(2)));
fprintf('p[H2A]= %8.4f->[H2A]= %10.4E\n', x(3), 10^(-x(3)));
fprintf('p[HA-]= %8.4f->[HA-]= %10.4E\n', x(4), 10^(-x(4)));
fprintf('p[A2-]= %8.4f->[A2-]= %10.4E\n', x(5), 10^(-x(5)));
```

Comment: The first half of the code, until the empty line, should be in a file called `diproticbuffer.m`. This is a function. The rest should be a script file, with whatever name you want. The run the script file.

Comment: @CrisLuengo not sure why they choose to 'import' the function in the main code instead of just using it though

Comment: the diproticbuffer function also has a undefined variable of 'c' in it' - a typo with c0 not in the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the function diproticbuffer in diproticbuffer.m and then the other code in solvediproticbuffer.m as specified in artical.

In the diproticbuffer function, you have a typo with c0 that it not in the original code.

Also remove the 'source' line from solvediproticbuffer.m

Running solvediproticbuffer should then work.